# Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, exception, datasource

Unable to start the Spring Boot Application in my Eclipse.

Its keep on showing console below.

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'
> defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean
> with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
> Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory
> method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine
> a suitable driver class

System should start the spring boot application successfully

Comment: Add your database properties here